# Creating VB.Net forms via code instead of in design mode

Tags: vb.net, forms, multiple-monitors

I'm using netzero hardware to manage the contents of a number of monitors.  My present solution creates a form in VB.Net that has a pixel offset corresponding to where I've placed the Monitors in display management in the control panel.  Each monitor has a dedicated form, and in each form are various objects.

The annoyance is that each form must be individually created (so far as I know) at design time.  I can't make an array of forms, coupled with an array of offsets and assign all the properties through code.

There ought to be a way to do this...it would simplify my coding and project management.

What I see on MSDN is either over my head or not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this in hardware yet, but it does compile w/o error:

```
Public Sub makeform()
    Dim MonitorForm(21) As Form
    Dim MPictureBoxes(21) As PictureBox

    Dim a As Integer


    For i As Integer = 0 To n 'up to 21
        MonitorForm(i) = New Form
        MonitorForm(i).Name = "Form" & (i + 1)
        MonitorForm(i).Text = "Form" & (i + 1)
        MonitorForm(i).Controls.Add(MPictureBoxes(i))
        MonitorForm(i).Location= new Point (x(i), y(i))
        With MPictureBoxes(i)
            .Name = "Picture Box " & Convert.ToString(i)
            .Image = Image.FromFile(CurrentPic(i))
            .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
            .Size = New Size(1920, 1080)

            '  Note you can set more of the PicBox's Properties here

        End With

    Next
    End Sub
```

Where I had gone wrong in my attempts at this was trying to do it this way

Dim Monitor(21) as New Form

That doesn't work, and the difference between Dim Monitor(21) as Form followed by monitor(i)= new Form
was simply too subtle for my present understand of classes, namespaces etc.

.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've had to give up on this approach and go back to creating n forms at design time (which means that they have names of form2...form22, putting each of them at manual start positions in design mode.  There just doesn't seem to be a way to do this with an array of forms.  So the code I have built around the messiness of forms2...forms22 works just fine, it's just going to be messy to maintain and elaborate on.

The solution to this may lie in system.screen classes, but the documentation on this is too advanced for me and I'm not finding good code examples for anything other than extracting data about how many screens there are - nothing about writing to them.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy in code. You want to make many instances of the same form. In this case, I have created a form in the designer called frmTest and I create many instances in code called frmNew:

```
Public Sub Main()
    For x = 100 To 400 Step 100
        For y = 100 To 700 Step 200
            Dim frmNew As New frmTest
            frmNew.Show()
            frmNew.Top = x
            frmNew.Left = y
            frmNew.Height = 100
            frmNew.Width = 200
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I have just used two loops to increment x and y values, but you could do this from a database or config file easily enough.

[image: This is how it displays]

Comment: I found a similar answer, but haven't tested it on hardware yet.  The problem with your code is that you lose the individual forms.  The code I've got now is: